# Skype hover features in Ubuntu?

Tags: video, skype

My parents have a Windows PC, and they have Skype on it. When they are on skype they can go on the internet and have a small video hovering over their browser.

I just want to know if there is a way to do this with Ubuntu skype. or if someone can write a code or something to make this possible.  I think a lot of people would love that function.

Answer (score 1):

Mentioned result can be achieved by opening Skype call window, right click on top menu bar of window and click on **Always on top** (as shown in below image)

[image: Skype Call Screenshot]

Now you can perform other tasks while Video chat window is still open.

Answer (score 0):

No. It is up to Skype developers to support this feature in future Skype releases.